# What is the meaning of Apastamba Dhramsutra 2:11:29:11?

Tags: dharma-shastras

I was reading Apastamba dhamrasutra and found this.

> 11. The knowledge which Śūdras and women possess is the completion (of all study).

About which knowledge, Apastamba is talking which women and even shudras posses but Brahmanas not?

Comment: May be the knowledge about survival. Because a shudra can survive in harsh conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what Georg Bühler [says](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/apastamba-dharma-sutra/d/doc116293.html#note-t-62466) in the footnote:

> [9]: [Manu II, 223](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199699.html). The meaning of the Sūtra is, that men ought not to study solely or at first such Śāstras as women or Śūdras also learn, but that at first they must study the Veda. See [Manu II, 168](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199641.html). **The knowledge which women and Śūdras possess is dancing, music, and other branches of the Arthaśāstra**.